# iterative k-ary tree pre- and postorder traversal

Tags: algorithm, tree, iteration

I have a k-ary tree, and I want to traverse it using iteration.

It is a scene graph, so every time I encounter a transform node I put its matrix on a stack, and every time a encounter a mesh node it is rendered using the matrix-stack. This both must be pre order.
But when all children of a transform node are handled, its matrix has to be popped from the matrix-stack. So I also need a post-order operation.

I found some algorithms for iterative post-order traversal, but always for binary trees and without the additional pre-order operations.

Comment: Pre-order and post-order are just a matter of interchanging the calls in your recursive code.

Comment: That is correct, but I dont want to use recursion. I want to traverse only using iterations like `while`.

Comment: If you don't use recursion, you have to also use a stack (perhaps the same stack as the matrix stack) to keep track of where you are. The precise definition of "where you are" depends on the details of your tree datastructure, but it might be, for example, an iterator into the list of children of a node.

Comment: A stack allows me to list which nodes I have discovered but not processed jet, but how does it help me with the post-order where I have to know when I have processed all children of a node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested, so treat with caution.

The basic idea to solve this is to mark the nodes as visited when first encountering them. Then put all the children on the stack.

If encountering a leaf-node without children, it can be savely printed/handled and popped from stack.

When the next node on the stack is already visited, all children must have been handled before, else the stack would not have been cleared this far.
We now know for interim nodes with arbitrary number of children that it can be handled in post-order.